# Forced to take annual leave for IT issue

Tags: law, leave, holidays

I am fully remote (office is around 4 hours away) and I have been forced to lose 2 days annual leave because of an IT issue.

This issue was due to a fire and losing one of the main servers, everyone who works in the office could still work but I lost all connection due to being remote.

Even though this issue is out of my control my boss has made me take it as annual leave for the days I’ve been unable to work. Any advice on this and if they are allowed to do that?

I would work if I could and I never chose to use my annual leave, this IT issue is still ongoing so I may lose even more annual leave that I eventually want to actually use for myself

Comment: What jurisdiction are you (and your employer, if different) in?

Comment: Both are England, thanks

Comment: Is there anything in your contract about being fully remote? Has your boss provided you alternatives (e.g. come to the office, he'll provide a hotel as means to reduce the travel burden)?

Answer (score 3):

You should talk to Citizens Advice and/or a lawyer ASAP but my unprofessional opinion is that this is illegal on the part of your employer; you cannot be forced to take leave because of a failure on the part of your employer.

Answer (score 1):

Poland:

In this situation (fire accident) Your boss can ask You to work on site or take annual leave.

There is possible other solution - 2 days free but work other days, normal free to match work days pool in 3 months period.

Answer (score 1):

I think given it is "technically possible" for you to work on site (however incredibly inconvenient), your job may require you to either: find a way to work or take leave.

One possibility is to see if your employer will cover a hotel closer to the work site for the duration of the outage (if they say no, you at least have a very good case to say you did everything you could to be there and should not be required to use leave time).

Answer (score 0):

As a UK based manager, I have to say this is standard practice, at least where I work. During previous IT outages this was the go-to practice for managers here. Those who were able to do meaningful, useful work could carry on. Those who were unfortunately left twiddling their thumbs took annual leave.

However, check your contract and check your terms of employment as that should give you the answer specific to your organisation.